# Quartz scheduler Not Working after exception [java.lang.IllegalStateException: HttpSession is invalid] 

Tags: java, exception, weblogic, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

I am currently working with Quartz scheduler in my web application to schedule a task after running the server and then repeat it in regular interval.
 
The process running fine in my development server but when deployed to production, it is good but sometimes when some exception occurred it stops working. I don't know whether the exception occured because of this scheduling process or there is something else.
The exception always occurred just before 2-3 minutes when scheduling should start.

Here is the stack trace.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: HttpSession is invalid
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.SessionData.getInternalAttribute(SessionData.java:690)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.SessionData.getInternalAttribute(SessionData.java:685)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.JDBCSessionData.dbRefresh(JDBCSessionData.java:428)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.JDBCSessionData.getFromDB(JDBCSessionData.java:102)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.JDBCSessionContext.getSessionDataFromDB(JDBCSessionContext.java:240)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.JDBCSessionContext.getSessionInternal(JDBCSessionContext.java:220)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.SessionContext$SessionInvalidator.cleanupExpiredSessions(SessionContext.java:938)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.SessionContext$SessionInvalidator$1.run(SessionContext.java:894)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.SessionContext$SessionInvalidator.timerExpired(SessionContext.java:888)
    at weblogic.timers.internal.TimerImpl.run(TimerImpl.java:273)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
```

anyway I am using WebLogic application server on both development and production.

Answer (score 1):

This might happen because your session becomes invalid when you try to read something from it.One thing you can do it here is that check your session time out entry in your configuration file.Most probably you need to increase the session time out value.